# Does Visual Studio 2008 Let You Save Workspaces (Sets of Open Code Files, and Their Order)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, usability

Allow me to define what I mean by a "Workspace", since this may have several different meanings, and I only talk about one..

Assume that you created a Project in VS2008, that contains 40 C# Code files.
For simplicity, let's name them A01..A40.

You can see all 40 of them in Solution Explorer,
and after you double click a file there, it is opened, and appears as a **Tab** in VS.

Now let's say sometimes you need to work on the first 10 files - A01..A10,
and on other times on other 10 (A11..A20), and so on.

Each time, you wish to have only the relevant 10 code files open (a tab for each),
and all other code files will be closed (no tabs).

So each time, you want to close all the open code files that Visual Studio shows as Tabs,
and then open other 10 code files.

You may also have some specific ordering that you like, in each set of 10 files.

Does VS2008 enable you to Save a workspace, and then load it?
So you can then save several different workspaces (of open files, and their order), and then load a workspace as needed.

"A Workspace" here contains only 2 things:
1) What code files are open (and hence shown as Tabs)
2) What is the Order of the open code files (order of the Tabs)

Comment: Visual Studio doesn’t have this. You can try searching some extensions, which might have some similar sort of.

Comment: I thought that might be the answer.. OK in that case I will create a small add-in by myself.. Thank you